# Collect method for streams doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, java-stream, collect

I'm testing the `collect` method for streams.  In this code I'm trying to build a single string from a stream of string by using a `StringBuilder` in the first case and concatenation of `String` in the second case.  I am not understanding why the second case produces an empty string.

```
    String[] strs = new String[] {"aaaaa", "bbbbbbb", "c", "dd"};
    
    
    StringBuilder sb = Arrays.stream(strs).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);
    
    System.out.println(sb);
    
    
    String s = Arrays.stream(strs).collect(String::new, String::concat, String::concat);
    
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the reason it doesn't work is that `String` is immutable.

`String::new` is a `Supplier<String>` that returns an empty `String`.

And your accumulator and combiner have no way of mutating it, since `String` is immutable.

Your code has the same effect as:

```
String s = new String ();
for (String str : strs) {
    s.concat(str);
}
```

The calls to `concat` produce new `String`s, and don't affect the value of the result `String`.

Since `String` is immutable, you can use immutable reduction (i.e. use `reduce` instead of `collect`):

```
String s = Arrays.stream(strs).reduce("",String::concat);
```

This will have the same result as:

```
String s = "";
for (String str : strs) {
    s = s.concat(str);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the collect method produces a mutable reduction.  Thank you, I thought that it behaved just like the reduce method.